# docker-compose error when I run bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, sidekiq, docker-compose

I have an error about my gemfile or bundle when I run some tasks like this one:

```
docker exec -it webapp_web_1 bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

error: **Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory**

or this command:

```
docker-compose logs worker

log:
Attaching to webapp_worker_1
worker_1 | Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

Dockerfile:

```
# === 1 ===
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby22:0.9.18
MAINTAINER Israel Barba Aceves "israel@yotepresto.com"

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libqt4-dev libqtwebkit-dev imagemagick

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]


# === 2 ===
# Start Nginx / Passenger
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

# === 3 ====
# Remove the default site
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default


# Add the nginx info
ADD webapp.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf

# === 4 ===
# Prepare folders
RUN mkdir /home/app/webapp



# === 5 ===
# Run Bundle in a cache efficient way
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile /tmp/
ADD Gemfile.lock /tmp/
RUN bundle install


#WORKDIR /webapp
#RUN RAILS_ENV=staging rake assets:precompile --trace

# === 6 ===
# Add the rails app
ADD . /home/app/webapp

RUN mkdir /home/app/webapp/tmp/cache/assets/staging
RUN mkdir /home/app/webapp/tmp/cache/assets/staging/sprockets
# RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/webapp/tmp/cache/assets/staging
RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/webapp

#RAILS_ENV=staging rake assets:precompile


# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432"
  volumes:
    - ytp-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379" 
  volumes:
    - ytp-redis:/var/lib/redis/data


web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/web
  ports:
    - "80"
  links:
    - redis
    - db
  environment:
    RACK_ENV: staging
    RAILS_ENV: staging

worker:
  build: .
  volumes_from:
    - web
  command: bundle exec sidekiq -e s -c 5 -C config/sidekiq.yml
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: staging
  links:
    - redis
    - db
```

Also I can't start Sidekiq from my configuration, I guess it is something about volumes but I'm not sure, I've edited this file in many ways without success... Any suggestions?

**Docker version:** 1.9.1

**Docker-compose version** 1.6.0rc2

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run "docker-compose run web bundle exec rake db:migrate"?

Comment: same error: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory I have to run migrations  inside the container

Comment: Also, sidekiq is a gem in your project, is there a reason why you are running it in a separate container? Since your web container is already linked to redis I suggest to use sidekiq from your web container and use foreman to run sidekiq and the rails server together.

Comment: and the performace is good? I will consider that solution, I wonder why the other tasks like RAKE raise errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to modify the last part of your Dockerfile to match the folders of your docker compose file:

```
WORKDIR /web
ADD Gemfile /web/
ADD Gemfile.lock /web/
RUN bundle install
```

Comment: @TopperH this worked for me but I can't explain it - can you point me to any docs to understand this more?

Comment: @mattsch, I think that the idea behind the OP configuration is that you don't have to run a full bundle install every time you update your Gemfile. Anyway this configuration is outdated and nowadays I would stick with the official ruby container and setup a docker-compose file following the official docs